# Add a File on a WebApi using POST and IFormFile in .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a **.net 5 WebApi** and i want to implement an endpoint to add files, I already did this on previous versions of .netcore but i'm getting the next error on Postman and Swagger:

> Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed. (Parameter 'requestUri')

my endpoint structure is the next:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile([FromForm]FileForAdd file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (await _fileService.AddFile(file))
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            throw new Exception("Creating the new File failed on save");
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

The FileForAdd class:

```
 public class FileForAdd
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

[this is the how i'm passing parameters on the postman client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7IOC.png)

Comment: According to your codes, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well. I suggest you could try to post more codes about your file controller and startup.cs class. According to the error message, this issue is due to the wrong url you have sent to the server.

Comment: can you check in the postman console what is being sent in the request. And in postman also try with capital param name, File